# JQuery Mobile and iPhone

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I need help from the experts here :)

## The story

Basically I am attempting to create a mobile website with a bottom navigation bar and so far it works fine on desktop (chrome and safari) and Android browsers but it doesn't work for iPhone browser which is Safari Mobile.

## The plugins

- JQuery Mobile 1.2
- Watusi iScroll plugin for JQuery Mobile
- JQuery 1.8.2

## Code

```
<div data-role="page" id="one">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Entry</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content" data-iscroll class="wrapper">                      
        <p>the content ...</p>  
    </div><!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#one" data-icon="custom">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#two" data-icon="custom">Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#three" data-icon="custom">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->                             
    </div>                                      
</div><!-- /page one -->
```

## Problem

The footer just doesn't show up on Safari Mobile. Please help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your HTML code in desktop safari with "user-agent" to iPhone, it will behave like the mobile safari and then use the inspect element to trace the exact problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

There is no error however I notice that there are two scroll bars, one is the default scrollbar and the other one is the iScroll.

It seems like the default scroll bar is not scrollable while the iScroll is. Thus it sort of hides the footer

Now I know more but I still don't know how to fix it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: why use iScroll with jquery mobile, you can do the same with the html css also?

Comment: because iScroll gives more native feeling and it I don't know how to write my own with HTML and CSS.